# How to use openssl to add the CA to the trusted chain within the PFX

Tags: windows, ssl, certificate, pfx, pkcs#7

*First of all, I'd like to make it clear this is my very first time dealing with certificates/keys/pfx/etc.. so please correct me if I'm wrong :)*

I'm having troubles add the CA of the server im connecting to, to my trusted chain using `openssl` in a PFX.

After creating the PFX I successfully added it to my computer using `mmc.exe` but found out its not gonna be useful as soon as i'll get the application running on a linux server.

I've been searching all over the net to find the correct command but couldnt find any.

A friend assumed I'll have to first export the certificate out of the existing pfx, then add the CA to its' trusted chain and generate a new pfx with it.

Unfortunately, couldn't find how to add to a certificate's trusted chain either.

Any help would be much appreciated! hope the question is clear enough, let me know if i could add anything to help you help me!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: There are plenty of similar questions on other sites in the Stack Exchange network. There are also questions on Stack Overflow before the site's polices changed. You might get better search results with PKCS#7 since PFX is roughly the same. Also see [Google: pkcs7 pfx](https://www.google.com/search?q=pkcs7+pfx).